# Compress image using Run Length coding and Huffman coding.

Tags: compression, huffman-code

I want to Compress image using Run Length coding and Huffman coding.

how to draw the appropriate Huffman coding diagram to get the new codes for obtaining the image compression.

How much compression ratio by using these techniques? Assume that the 16 gray levels are coded into 4 bits.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What have you tryed so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: "How much compression ratio" always depends on your data.